# xcode convert iPhone to iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

help please. my code that change UIImageView is:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {

background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];

}
```

It works good on iPhone and also on iPad but, how can I change "myImage.png" to "myImageHD.png" when I will run this app on my iPad???? I just need to show myImageHD if my app will run on iPad. IT CAN BE DONE WITH XIB FILE, BUT I NEED WITH CODE TO FIX IT. To detect if app run on iPad, and show myImageHD. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this,

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
   background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
} else { //UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad is for iPad
   background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageHD.png"];
}
```

Another way to do this would be,

```
if ([(NSString*)[UIDevice currentDevice].model isEqualToString:@"iPad"] } { //As per the below comment, for iPad simulator the string will be "iPad simulator"
    background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageHD.png"];
} else {
    background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
}
```

`UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` also can be used to check if the current device is iPad or iPhone. Instead of `[[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom]` in the above if condition, you can use `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` also.

Comment: the second method is not suitable if you are trying in simulator, since the model string will be "iPad" in device and "iPad simulator" in simulator

Comment: @Deepak, Thanks. I didnt think about that earlier. Added as a comment in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
 - (void) viewDidLoad {

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageHD.png"];
    }
    else{
        background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use below code

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {

if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageHD.png"];
}
else
background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;

if([deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPhone"])
{
     // it's an iPhone
}
```

this will help you, but i dont think that it a good try using same XIB and changing the image only! 
regards